# Update feed more frequently

Tags: feed

When i publish new posts, i notice the new posts do not appear in the feed `http://mysite.com/feed` instantaneously, there is always lag time, one or several hours.

When i change something in `wp-includes/feed-rss2.php` file (just `echo 'test'`), it also takes one or 2 hour to see the `test` word in `http://mysite.com/feed`, it means wordpress only use that file periodically.

Anyone know how to solve this problem? I want whenever the `http://mysite.com/feed` page is open in browser, it must use `wp-includes/feed-rss2.php` file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like the pages WordPress makes normally, feeds are generated on-demand, they're not "rebuilt" or "updated" or any sort of thing like that. So posts will appear in the feed at the exact instant that they are published.

If you're seeing a lag time, then you may be using a caching plugin, such as WP-Super-Cache, or some form of feed redistribution service, such as FeedBurner, which is holding a copy of the feed for some period of time and only refreshing from the actual feed periodically.

In this case, you need to either configure the caching plugin to not cache the feed, or stop using the feedburner-like service.

Comment: When i turn-off the wp-super-cache plugin, the problem is resolved. Thank Otto!

Comment: Super Cache has options to specifically not cache feeds. Turn it back on, check those settings. Then clear the cache. Should work fine then.